# Iterate las files to Add Surface Information

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator, las

I'm trying to run 'Add Surface Information' to populate elevation data from 100s of las files to a polygon in Model Builder.

However it doesn't seem to matter whether I use Files or Datasets as an iterator,  I can't connect the dataset output to the input of the 'Add Surface Info' tool. The only option I get is to use it as a precondition or Environment.

Using 'Extract LAS' or 'Collect Values' as intermediates doesn't help, but the tool works fine on a single LAS file.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Model]

Comment: Try creating a LAS Dataset https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/las-dataset/creating-a-las-dataset.htm which is a valid input into Add Surface Information https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm then you no longer need to iterate.

Comment: I did try that but the tool didn't produce an output from a LAS dataset; it ran for hours without ending, even when I created a LAs dataset from just 3 tiles.

Comment: You may need to rasterize your LAS for better performance https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000052000000 then use the output raster as your surface..